# ServerHttpResponseDecorator causes swagger-ui to no longer load

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, spring-webflux, swagger-ui

I am trying to add some logging around each response by using a ServerHttpResponseDecorator. The responses are coming back fine via postman, however I’ve noticed I can no longer load my swagger UI (just get a blank white screen).

This does not work, in that the swagger-ui no longer loads.

```
class ResponseLoggingDecorator(
    delegate: ServerHttpResponse
) : ServerHttpResponseDecorator(delegate) {
    override fun writeWith(body: Publisher<out DataBuffer>): Mono<Void> {
        val buffer = Mono.from(body)
        return super.writeWith(buffer.doOnNext { dataBuffer: DataBuffer ->
        })
    }
}
```

But this does work (swagger UI loads), a bit obvious but shows something is wrong with the doOnNext?

```
class ResponseLoggingDecorator(
    delegate: ServerHttpResponse
) : ServerHttpResponseDecorator(delegate) {
    override fun writeWith(body: Publisher<out DataBuffer>): Mono<Void> {
        return super.writeWith(body)
    }
}
```

I'm not hugely knowledgeable on how it works, so I might be wrong, but it should be fine?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the toMono(), it should instead be toFlux()